# Cant Log in to Adobe Connect server using HTTP header authentication - Single Sign On

Tags: adobe, single-sign-on, adobe-connect

I want to log in some users just with their login names (SSO). So I think http header authentication is the way to go.

I did everything what the doc says (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/8.0/webservices/connect_8_webservi ces.pdf)

I added a line to custom.ini for HTTP_AUTH_HEADER (

> HTTP_AUTH_HEADER=white50

)

My web.xml fil contains filter settings below.

I am requesting "https://example.com/api/xml?action=login&external-auth=use" with http header (white50=adobe_connect_loginname).

But I always get no-access error response from AC server. I could not authenticate user with its login name without password.

Could you help please.

```
web.xml:
```

---

```
<filter-name>HeaderAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>

<filter-class>com.macromedia.airspeed.servlet.filter.HeaderAuthentica tionFilter</filter-class>

<init-param>

  <param-name>ignore-pattern-0</param-name>

  <param-value>/api/</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

  <param-name>ignore-pattern-1</param-name>

  <param-value>/common/</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

  <param-name>ignore-pattern-2</param-name>

  <param-value>/servlet/gateway/</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

  <param-name>ignore-pattern-3</param-name>

  <param-value>/servlet/mirror</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

  <param-name>ignore-pattern-4</param-name>

  <param-value>/servlet/testbuilder</param-value>

</init-param>

<init-param>

  <param-name>ignore-pattern-5</param-name>

  <param-value>/main</param-value>

</init-param>
```

```
<filter-name>HeaderAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your only problem, but the request you're testing with...
  https://example.com/api/xml?action=login&external-auth=use
...will not be handled by the header authentication filter. It's configured to be ignored by this stanza in the web.xml:-

```
  <param-name>ignore-pattern-0</param-name>
  <param-value>/api/</param-value>
```

Try with the standard login page. If you still have troubles, it might be worth excerpting the relevant lines from the debug log.